# map subscribe getAll

Tags: angular, rxjs

In Angular, is it possible to filter the HttpRequest, before subscribing it? As you can see below, I would like to get **the property 'name'** of Users only, using a kind of the following code. I already tried 'map' and some RxJS map-operators, but unfortunately, it does not succeed me to 'extract the name property' from the service.. What am I doing wrong?

```
this.userService.getAll().map(users => users['name']).subscribe(filterNames => { console.log(filterNames); });
```

Comment: What does `this.userService.getAll()` return?

Comment: ++ You should be using the `pipe` operator :  
`this.userService.getAll().pipe(map(users => users.name)).subscribe(filterNames =>  console.log(filterNames));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about what getAll returns but I assume it returns an array of users.
If you want an array of user names your pipe should look like this:

```
this.userService.getAll().pipe(
    map(users => users.map(user => user.name))
).subscribe(userNames => console.log(userNames));
```

First use rxjs `map` operator to map the result (the user array) to something else. 
Then use `Array.map` to run the actual conversion of the user array to a userName array.